# Implementing Iterable in a Doubly Linked List in Java

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I've built a DoublyLinkedList that has all the normal methods (add(), remove(), isEmpty(), size() etc etc.)

This list holds ListNodes that have ListNode next, ListNode prev and T inf fields. (so very simple / classic here aswell)

My question is, how do I make my DLL iterable. 
From what I gathered I need to implement the Iterable interface, and define an iterator() method that returns an Iterator.

This is the part that I don't understand. What does that iterator() method do? How do I write it?

Any pointers appreciated.
Thanks in advance
PS: I know i should use the containers already available in the java packages, but I need to do it myself in this case.

Comment: Even if you are not allowed to use the existing collections, it is worth having a look at their code, to see concrete examples of how an `Iterable` can be implemented.

Comment: @Péter: though this seems like a learning exercise, in which case it's worthwhile to struggle a bit, first.

Answer (score 1):

The `iterator()` method would return an instance of an extra class. This would keep track of what node the iterator was on, and allow you to check for the presence of more nodes (via `hasNext()`) and move to the next node (via `next()`).

This *has* to be a separate object from the list itself, as there can be multiple iterators going over the same collection at the same time. It's an extra bit of state, basically: where you are. Don't forget that the iterator starts off *before* the first element, logically - the first call to `next()` moves to the first element.

Comment: @peti, Since it's a double-linked list, it is also a good idea to implement the List.listIterator() method for traversing a list in both directions.